# How to add padding between text and image in SpannableStringBuilder

Tags: android, spannablestringbuilder

I want to add a image in text. I used SpannableStringBuilder to achieve that. But I am not able to give padding to the image icon. Please help me to add padding to the image icon.

My code snippet:

```
String text = "Hello world! ";

        SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);
        ssb.setSpan(new ImageSpan(this, R.drawable.tick), text.length() - 1, text.length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        tvMainText.setText(ssb, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Output:

[image]

Here I want to add right and left padding for the image. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding the desired paddings to the drawable itself:

```
Drawable tick = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.tick);
LayerDrawable paddedTick = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[]{tick});
paddedTick.setLayerInset(0, paddingLeft, 0, paddingRight, 0);

ssb.setSpan(new ImageSpan(paddedTick), text.length() - 1, text.length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
```

Or create a custom drawable:

```
public class PaddedDrawable extends Drawable {
    
    private Drawable drawable;
    
    public PaddedDrawable(Drawable drawable, int paddingStartPx, int paddingTopPx, int paddingEndPx, int paddingBottomPx) {
        this.drawable = drawable;
        setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() + paddingStartPx + paddingEndPx, drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() + paddingTopPx + paddingBottomPx);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
        drawable.draw(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBoundsChange(@NonNull Rect bounds) {
        super.onBoundsChange(bounds);
        drawable.setBounds(
            bounds.centerX() - drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), bounds.centerY() - drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(),
            bounds.centerX() + drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), bounds.centerY() + drawable.getIntrinsicHeight()
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {}

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(@Nullable ColorFilter colorFilter) {}

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
Drawable tick = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.tick);
Drawable paddedTick = new PaddedDrawable(tick, paddingLeft, 0, paddingRight, 0);
ssb.setSpan(new ImageSpan(paddedTick), text.length() - 1, text.length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
```

Comment: No, image is not showing using this code.

Comment: @VijayadhasChandrasekaran could you try specifying the second parameter of the `ImageSpan` constructor? e.g. `new ImageSpan(paddedTick, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE)`

Comment: Tried. But No luck. Stim image is not showing. Only text is showing.

Comment: I think full text not copied. Some text are clipped in your comment.

Comment: @VijayadhasChandrasekaran updated the answer, could you please try the second approach?

Comment: @VijayadhasChandrasekaran if it worked for you, please let me know, I'll update the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255528/discussion-between-vijayadhas-chandrasekaran-and-vlad-guriev).

Comment: Your idea gave me a solution. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`String text = "Hello world! ";`

Define

`text = "Hello world! *symbol* ";`

`Int startIndex = text.indexOf("*symbol*");`

pass the indices of the first and second asterisk (*) as start and end params of setSpan respectively like this

`ssb.setSpan(new ImageSpan(this, R.drawable.tick), startIndex, startIndex + 8, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);`

Comment: This code is add image in the text.  I want to add padding to the image.

Comment: you can add padding with space in the text

Comment: use space before and after *symbol*

Comment: 20 dp padding want to add. Need to add 20 space?? 50 dp mean 50 space to the string?? Is this correct way??

Comment: No, one space will be equal to the text size. If your text is of size 20sp, one space will create a 20sp padding

Comment: No. I want to add padding in dp calculation. Some times 10, sometimes 50, sometimes 100.